# Excel field abbreviated unless double clicked

Tags: excel

We have a problem with automatically created Excel documents. I'm not sure if it is related to how we create the document or else is a viewer problem. But in any case, it's confusing.

When opening the Excel document, the content of some text fields is abbreviated by just displaying some short postfix of the content. On double click, the full content is visible. What is confusing is that the full content would well fit into the fields as it is displayed.

How to prevent such abbreviated fields?

I've attached two screen shots showing the problem.

first column of line 13 is abbreviated:
[image: first column of line 13 is abbreviated]

after double click, the first column of line 13 is displayed correctly:
[image: after double click, the first column of line 13 is displayed correctly]

For a sample document, follow [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_mqOWfkQ42LUzJsV3BLTWJMd1U/view?usp=sharing). The document shows correctly in my firefox browser but faulty when seen with Excel on Windows 10.

Comment: It seems that you have a line feed at end of the data. Adjust the row to a taller height to see the data or repair the export process to remove trailing line feeds. A line feed can be generated in the Find & Replace window with [ctrl]+j.

Comment: Turning off **Wrap Text** seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: Indeed, Wrap Text seems to be the issue. Now I have to investigate how I can create my document with this property being unset.  Please add your comment as answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: There was already a comment to my response that you disregarded.